# Change order of words in Excel text cell to ensure % values appear before the words to which they relate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of cells in Excel, where the text is a sequence of words and percentages. For example:
`Caladoc 30% Merlot 30% Grenache Noir 30%, Cinsault 10%`

I need to change the order  of these, so the percentage precedes the text to which it relates rather than follows it, and separate each group with a comma.

In this case, the result I want is:
`30% Caladoc, 30% Merlot, 30% Grenache Noir, 10% Cinsault`

Pseudo code for this might be:

- Parse the words, i.e. with a space separator
- Group words together until reaching first word containing a % character
- Move the word containing the % character to the front of the words grouped together
- Repeat. If there is another group, add a comma at the end of the previous text before adding more.

I can picture doing this with by creating an array of words, but I do not know how to change the order of array entries.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function ReOrderGrapes(ByVal Value As String) As String

    ' start with an array of all words in the input value.
    Dim words As Variant

    ' we use the VBA.Strings.Split function to split the string at each space.
    words = Split(Value, " ")

    ' iterate each word; we know how many there are so use a For loop.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)

        ' copy the current word into a local variable:
        Dim word As String
        word = words(i)

        If ArrayContains("%", word) Then
            ' Somehow change the order of the words. storing the word back into the array
            ' but with a different index than here
            words(i) = word

            ' need a way to add the comma "," at the end of the last word, if another word follows
            ' ?
        Else
            ' Not sure. Maybe just go to next word
        End If
                
    Next

    ' assemble the words array back into a string, and return it:
    ReOrderGrapes = Join(words, " ")

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Public Function ReOrderGrapes(ByVal Value As String) As String

    Dim words As Variant, wd, s, rv, sep
    
    words = Split(Replace(Value, ",", ""), " ") 'remove existing commas
    
    s = ""
    rv = ""
    For Each wd In words
        If wd Like "*%" Then
            'got a % - add that to 'rv' before adding whatever is in 's'
            rv = rv & sep & wd & " " & s
            sep = ", "
            s = ""
        Else
            'not a % - just append to 's'
            s = s & IIf(Len(s)>0, " ", "") & wd
        End If
    Next wd
    
    If Len(s) > 0 Then rv = rv & sep & wd & " " & s
    ReOrderGrapes = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, does the job exactly. Very neat solution.